# Getting the full permissions applied to a user in AD

Tags: powershell

I have been getting the full permissions applied to a user in AD, through the Security tab in the users properties in AD. Also , I want to get displayname,samaccountname,employeeID attribute too.  How can I do that ?

Thanks,

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | %{(Get-ACL "AD:$($_.distinguishedname)").access}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are after is something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmployeeID | 
Select-Object DisplayName, SamAccountName, EmployeeID,
              @{Name = 'Permissions'; Expression = {(Get-ACL "AD:$($_.DistinguishedName)").Access}}
```

---

Unknown of what exactly you want in the output, here's what you can do as alternative:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmployeeID | 
ForEach-Object {
    $permissions = foreach ($perm in (Get-ACL "AD:$($_.DistinguishedName)").Access) {
        '{0}: {1}' -f $perm.AccessControlType, $perm.IdentityReference
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName        = $_.DisplayName
        SamAccountName     = $_.SamAccountName
        EmployeeID         = $_.EmployeeID
        Permissions        = ($permissions | Sort-Object -Unique) -join [environment]::NewLine
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arbelac That depends on what properties of Access you want to see.. Maybe you want something like `(Get-ACL "AD:$($_.DistinguishedName)").Access | Select IdentityReference, AccessControlType` in the expression ??

Comment: Hi Man, I have a question related to the TLS cipher suite.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552469/powershell-use-object-of-type-system-net-security-ciphersuitespolicy-on-the   Is there any comment?