# Powershell - Use object of type 'System.Net.Security.CipherSuitesPolicy' on the Windows platform

Tags: powershell, encryption, tls1.2

I am using this code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
$httpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
try
{
    $task = $httpClient.GetAsync('http://www.example.com')
    $task.wait()
    $res = $task.Result
    if ($res.isFaulted)
    {
        write-host $('Error: Status {0}, reason {1}.' -f [int]$res.Status, $res.Exception.Message)
    }
    return $res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
}
catch [Exception]
{
    write-host ('Error: {0}' -f $_)
} finally {
    if($null -ne $res)
    {
        $res.Dispose()
    }
}
```

This works well. What I want to do is that set the specific Cipher Suite.

AFAIK, The default client behavior for secure channel-based client/server information exchange is that the best cipher available (based on those enabled in the registry) is offered when the connection is being initiated (ClientHello part of the TLS handshake), but ultimately the server decides on the cipher that's going to be utilized.

Also as far as I have researched,  Utilize a 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' instance to access the desired web resource, which should be instantiated by providing a 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler' instance in the respective constructor. This lets you define cipher suites through the 'SslOptions' property of the 'SocketsHttpHandler' class, which in turn contains an instance of the 'SslClientAuthenticationOptions' class that has a 'CipherSuitesPolicy' property.

I have found that it works on Linux / MacOS only, because you can't instantiate an object of type 'System.Net.Security.CipherSuitesPolicy' on the Windows platform.

As summary, is it not possible to do this on the Windows platform?

Answer (score -1):

To set a specific cipher suite for an `HttpClient` in PowerShell on Windows, you're correct that the `System.Net.Security.CipherSuitesPolicy` class, which is straightforward to use on Linux and macOS, is not directly usable on Windows. This limitation is due to the different ways Windows and Unix-based systems handle SSL/TLS settings.

On Windows, cipher suites are typically managed at the OS level rather than the application level. This means that changes to allowed cipher suites usually involve modifying system settings rather than application code.

Since directly setting the cipher suite in `HttpClient` using `CipherSuitesPolicy` isn't an option on Windows, you could create a script to modify the Windows registry to enable a specific cipher suite. After this, your existing `HttpClient` script will use the configured cipher suite, as Windows applies these settings at the system level.

Here's a PowerShell script to enable a specific cipher suite on Windows:

```
# Define the cipher suite you want to enable
$cipherSuite = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

# Registry path for SSL cipher suites
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002"

# Check if the registry path exists and create if it doesn't
if (-not (Test-Path $registryPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force
}

# Set the desired cipher suite in the registry
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "Functions" -Value $cipherSuite

# Output for confirmation
Write-Host "Cipher suite set to $cipherSuite in the registry."
```

This script sets the specified cipher suite as the only enabled cipher suite for SSL/TLS connections on your Windows system. Replace `"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"` with the cipher suite you wish to use.

#### Important Notes:

- This script modifies system-level settings, which affects all applications using SSL/TLS on your system.
- Use this script with caution and understand the security implications.
- After running this script, your `HttpClient` connections will use the specified cipher suite, provided the server supports it.

#### To revert the changes:

You would need to set the "Functions" value back to its original state or delete the created registry key if it wasn't present initially. For the record, in my personal computer, this path is currently empty prior to making any changes.